# WiFi not working on Ubuntu 12.04 after upgrade from 10.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

After the upgrade from Ubuntu 10.04 to Ubuntu 12.04, my system stopped working.

I tried many many commands even then it didn't seem to work. It displayed: `Ubuntu is running in low graphics`

I couldn't find any solutions on the Internet. So I went into recovery mode and and cleaned my files and I worked for a whole month.

I guess 12.04 is still running in low graphics as I can see from my eyes its really lame to see this 12.04.

Now I knew that my system space was low so I cleared nearly 2 GB data.

Whenever I try to connect to my WiFi it says authentication required by WiFi network. I typed the password then it connects, but after 3 seconds the same message appears.

Repeating to authenticate didn't work. My WiFi is working as I am posting this from my nexus from the same WiFi to which 12.04 is now connecting.

my laptop is a Samsung RV510.

somebody please help me with the WiFi problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install 13.10 from a LiveDVD and they tell me it will preserve your home folder. There is better/proper driver support there.